# Disallow leading spaces entire table column with Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to apply data validation for an entire table column, instead of applying the validation to each single cell, in order to disallow leading spaces. I tried selecting the entire table column and entering a custom validation that looks like this:

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[ColumnName]")=TRIM(INDIRECT("Table1[ColumnName]"))
```

I get no error, though it does not give any errors when trying to enter or change a value from say "Input" to:

> " Input" or "Input "

It works however when I try it on a single cell, say, `A2`:

```
=A2=TRIM(A2)
```

Can what I'm trying to do be done? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you highlight the range you want to apply the validation to and use the formula you've already used for your single cell:

```
=A2=TRIM(A2)
```

Then it will be applied relatively to the rest of the cells in the range because you haven't used absolute cell references in the formula (e.g. `$A$2`). Here's a little more information on relative and absolute cell references if you're interested - [Absolute/Relative Cell References](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

For example, highlighting cells `A2:A20` and adding the custom data validation formula of `=A2=TRIM(A2)` will apply `=A2=TRIM(A2)` to cell `A2` but cell `A6` will have the custom validation formula of `=A6=TRIM(A6)`.